# Как заменить данные из многомерного массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Как в данном массиве найти элемент и поменять соседнее значение?
т.е. находим элемент [ID] => 172 и меняем [SORT] => 140 на [SORT] => 200

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 187
            [NAME] => Новая сортировка
            [CODE] => NEW_SORT
            [SORT] => 100            
            [VALUE] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 185=100
                    [1] => 173=200
                    [2] => 172=300
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 180
            [NAME] => Код цвета
            [CODE] => COLOR
            [SORT] => 97
            [VALUE] => 4956175d-8376-11e9-9251-e41f13e5248e
        )
  [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 172
            [NAME] => Столы
            [CODE] => TABLE
            [SORT] => 140
            [VALUE] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 624
                    [1] => 628
                    [2] => 626
                    [3] => 614
                    [4] => 630
                )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 185
            [NAME] => Тумбы 
            [CODE] => TUMBA          
            [SORT] => 510            
            [VALUE] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 651
                    [1] => 616
                    [2] => 622
                )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 173
            [NAME] => Шкафы
            [CODE] => WARDROBE
            [SORT] => 520
            [VALUE] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 618
                    [1] => 620
                )
```

array_replace затирает весь массив, оставляя только тот участок что изменил

Comment: что мешает использовать обычный цикл с условием совпадения ID?

Answer (score 2):

С помощью цикла перебора массива:

```php
foreach ($data as $key => $array) {
    if ($array['ID'] == 172) {
        $data[$key]['SORT'] = 200;
    }
}
```

Comment: Все просто работает, спасибо!
А как подставить данные из другого массива? т.е. не просто число, а массив вида (172 => 200), (175 => 300)?

Comment: Просто вместо значения "200" подставляете нужный вам массив или объект.

Answer (score 1):

С использованием array_map() и передачей в пользовательскую ф-ю данных о новых SORT-значениях:

```
<?php

$sort = [
    180 => 300,
    172 => 200
];

$input = [
    [
        'ID' => 187,
        'SORT' => 100,
        'NAME' => 'Новая сортировка',
        'CODE' => 'NEW SORT',
        'VALUE' => ['185=100', '173=200', '172=300']
    ],
    [
        'ID' => 180,
        'SORT' => 97,
        'NAME' => 'Код цвета',
        'CODE' => 'COLOR',
        'VALUE' => '4956175d-8376-11e9-9251-e41f13e5248e'
    ],
    [
        'ID' => 172,
        'SORT' => 140,
        'NAME' => 'Столы',
        'CODE' => 'TABLE',
        'VALUE' => [624, 628, 626, 614, 630]
    ]
];

$output = array_map(
    function ($itm) use ($sort) {
        $id = $itm['ID'];
        if (isset($sort[$id])) {
            $itm['SORT'] = $sort[$id];
        }
        return $itm;
    },
    $input
);

var_dump($output);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dee91baedd0edad4da98bea4c1a72befd123cccb)

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу ни одной причины не использовать простой `for`:

```
$searchId = 172;
$replaceSortValue = 200;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if ($array[$i]['ID'] == $searchId) {
        $array[$i]['SORT'] = $replaceSortValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach` более универсален, т.к. ваш код работает только с числовыми массивами.

Comment: @HakuKimura не вижу в коде ТС других ключей. Какой исходник - такой ответ